# Prevent interruption of moving file long time

Tags: 14.04, copy

I have blank screen after 10 minutes in Ubuntu 14.04. 
However, I noticed that it also interrupts any processes going on in my laptop, such as copying file from my SSD disc to external SSD. 
The amount of data transfer is about 2-5 hours.

How can you prevent the interruption of moving file long time?

Comment: You seem to either have a faulty install or your hardware is broken. For the faulty install, you could look into the "Live" options of Ubuntu, and for your hardware, the most easy way to transfer your files would be to hook up your SSD disk to another computer (not faulty) and copy from there to your external SSD.

Comment: I think there is a command to prevent suspend, but I can not remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open system settings -> power and set "suspend when inactive" from 10 minutes to never.

Comment: So when the system is transferring data between drives it is considered "inactive"? Additional explanation in your answer would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful, I agree too. I think copying in OSX is not considered as *inactive* state. Linux then again thinks so. I opened a new thread about this question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218348/16920